# Built DWH From Father-Child table efficiently with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the last two days, I've been trying to find an efficient solution as most dynamic as possible but I can't make it. Do you have a hint for the following example? I tried a recursive call to get the "level" or the native join so far with the results below.

I have "initTable":

```
parent | child
-------+------
   A   |  H
   A   |  B
   A   |  C
   B   |  D
   B   |  G
   C   |  F
   D   |  E
```

I want to have "finalTable": (in the bescase with dynamically create columns "levelX"

```
level1 | level2 | level 3 | level 4
-------+--------+---------+---------
   A   |   A    |   A     |   H
   A   |   A    |   C     |   F
   A   |   A    |   B     |   G
   A   |   B    |   D     |   E
```

**Attempt #1**: recursive way to get the level

Question: Is there a possibility to create the for each level a column during the recursion?

```
WITH recTable (father, child, lev) AS 
(
    SELECT
        p1.father,
        p1.child,
        0 as lev
    FROM 
        initTable AS p1 
    WHERE 
        p1.father = 'A' 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        p1.father,
        p1.child,
        lev+1
    FROM 
        initTable AS p1 
    INNER JOIN 
        recTable as p2 ON p1.father = p2.child
) 
SELECT * FROM ASD
```

**Attempt #2**: but with "wrong" order

Here I would need to fill up the columns "backwards" somehow...

```
SELECT
    p1.child AS Level 1,
    p2.child AS Level 2,
    p3.child AS Level 3,
    p4.child AS Level 4
FROM 
    initTable p1 
LEFT JOIN 
    initTable p2 ON p1.child = p2.father
LEFT JOIN 
    initTable p3 ON p2.child = p3.father
LEFT JOIN 
    initTable p4 ON p3.child = p4.father
WHERE
     p1.father= 'A'
```

Does someone know a nice and efficient way to solve this problem? I feel like I m pretty close but I just can't solve it so far.

Comment: I don't see the logic in what you're trying to achieve. E.g, in row 1, A-A-A-H, what does this mean? To me it looks like it would simply be A-H, but you're padding it with the top-level parent so you have values in all fields?

Comment: Exactly, I want to have the "parent" values in all fields for dwh reporting reasons

Comment: @marc_s: thanks for editing the post (now I get it how to do it by example)

Comment: Ok, the answer I've provided will do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is dynamic and will work for your example, as well as for any with more/less parent/child relationships:

```
-- Get the number of required fields

SELECT
    parent
    , child
    , 1 [level]
INTO #checking
FROM initTable
WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT child FROM initTable)
;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #checking c JOIN initTable t ON c.child = t.parent)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #checking

    SELECT
        t.parent
        , t.child
        , (SELECT MAX([level]) + 1 FROM #checking)
    FROM
        #checking c
        JOIN initTable t ON c.child = t.parent
    ;

    DELETE
    FROM #checking
    WHERE [level] <> (SELECT MAX([level]) FROM #checking)
    ;

END
;

DECLARE @requiredLevels int = (SELECT TOP 1 [level] + 1 FROM #checking)
;

DROP TABLE #checking
;

-- Build a dynamic statement for the SELECT fields

DECLARE
    @fieldSQL varchar(1000) = ''
    , @fieldsN int = @requiredLevels
;

WHILE @fieldsN > 0
BEGIN

    IF @fieldsN > 2
        BEGIN

            DECLARE
                @coalesceFields varchar(1000) = ''
                , @coalesceN int = @fieldsN

            WHILE @coalesceN > 1
            BEGIN

                IF @coalesceFields = ''
                    SET @coalesceFields = 'L' + CAST(@coalesceN AS varchar) + '.parent'
                ELSE
                    SET @coalesceFields = @coalesceFields + ', L' + CAST(@coalesceN AS varchar) + '.parent'
                ;

                SET @coalesceN = @coalesceN - 1

            END

            SET @fieldSQL = @fieldSQL + ', COALESCE(' + @coalesceFields + ') [level ' + CAST(@requiredLevels - @fieldsN + 1 AS varchar) + ']'

        END
    ELSE
        SET @fieldSQL = @fieldSQL + ', L' + CAST(@fieldsN AS varchar) + '.' + CASE WHEN @fieldsN = 1 THEN 'child' ELSE 'parent' END + ' [level ' + CAST(@requiredLevels - @fieldsN + 1 AS varchar) + ']'
    ;

    SET @fieldsN = @fieldsN - 1

END

SET @fieldSQL = SUBSTRING(@fieldSQL, 3, LEN(@fieldSQL) - 2)

-- Build a dynamic statement for the LEFT JOINs

DECLARE
    @joinSQL varchar(1000) = ''
    , @joinsN int = 2

WHILE @joinsN <= @requiredLevels
BEGIN

    SET @joinSQL = @joinSQL + ' LEFT JOIN initTable L' + CAST(@joinsN AS varchar) + ' ON L' + CAST(@joinsN - 1 AS varchar) + '.' + CASE WHEN @joinsN = 2 THEN 'child' ELSE 'parent' END + ' = L' + CAST(@joinsN AS varchar) + '.child'

    SET @joinsN = @joinsN + 1

END

-- Build the final SQL statement and execute

DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000) =
    '
        SELECT ' + @fieldSQL + '
        FROM
            (
                SELECT child
                FROM initTable
                WHERE child NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM initTable)
            ) L1' + @joinSQL

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Hi Chris! Thank you for the quick reply and solution - it works nearly perfect and helped me a lot (took me some time to understand it though). It solves the backwards-dynamic building perfect and I m working on adopting it to fill the "A" values up to level 1 (which are currently empty in my case, i.e. row 1 in my example above results in: _ | _ | A | H instead of A | A | A | H).

Comment: Have you changed the script at all? I was getting the "A" values filling up the row, the `COALESCE` statements were taking care of that. It might be worth adding a `PRINT @SQL` and debugging that as a static query to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, now it works for me too - I did not notice there was one relation _  | A in the initTable so "_" where filled up. Now it works! Thank you so much for your help, really great!